# Motherboard Screw Possible Damage?

Tags: motherboard

I was recently running a computer and setup the operating system on it, however when reassembling the side panels afterwards I noticed that it sounded like there was a loose screw somewhere. After tilting the case a bunch of times, I located a mounting screw freely moving around the back PCI ports. (This is a computer that lays horizontally.)

While the computer was being run, the case was being moved very minimally if at all, and I'm not sure where the screw was originally, but since it is a horizontally laying computer it may have been on the motherboard originally.

If the motherboard still works before and after the removal of the screw, should I be worried about any permanent damage done to it, or would it have shorted something out and caused it to not POST at all if there was damage?

Comment: The slight movement and removal of the screw won't hurt anything. The only thing that could have been a problem is if the computer was on while you moved the case, the screw made contact with the motherboard and shorted it out.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in the post - I meant that the screw was most likely on the motherboard while the computer is running (but wasn't moving). I believe it would've been on the top of the motherboard since I lay it horizontally, but because I was tilting it a bunch afterwards I'm not sure where it was originally.

Comment: You ask ..."**`If the motherboard still works before and after the removal of the screw, should I be worried about any permanent damage done to it`**". I say ... "*`Boot it up and test it and confirm all works with it as expected. If there are obvious problems, then worry about it, if there are not, then use it or deploy it out, etc. Deal with it if there's an issue with it operating, otherwise, don't sweat it!!`*"

Comment: I assembled and started the computer up again and it is working fine so far. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Motherboard Screw Possible Damage?**
>
> If the motherboard still works before and after the removal of the
>   screw, should I be worried about any permanent damage done to it?

### Here's my advice. . .

- *Boot it up and test it to confirm all works with it as expected. If there are obvious problems, then worry about it, troubleshoot
  further, etc. If there are not any obvious problem during your test,
  then use it, deploy it out, etc.*

Deal with it if there's an issue with it operating; otherwise, don't worry about it and move on!!